# Winforms controls size random on user's screen

Tags: .net, winforms

I've got a commercial .net winforms app (it's also using Krypton Toolkit if that matters) , on most users screens the form are drawn normally, but a couple of users screens , some of the controls (mostly multiline textboxes) are not of the size I've specified and show up larger / hide each other. What could be causing this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you anchored all your controls properly??

Comment: Do those users have a different dpi set?

Comment: Paul : The controls are all anchored to top - left, and I've deactivated all window size changes
Joey : I'm not sure , but only some control sizes change , the other control sizes are normal

Comment: Font enlarging, custom fonts, localization, screen magnification, themes, screen DPI, skins, fluid layouts, and screen effects can all change WinForm control sizes. You need to post screen shots of the unaffected and affected forms.

Comment: I found out what was happening. Krypton Toolkit uses the system's font size unlesss you specify otherwise